# How to roll up a Time-series like table in MySQL to get the most up date value that is not null?

Tags: mysql, sql, time-series

I have a table of time-series data like data in SQL which follows the following format:

*Note: Each customer_ID can have multiple transaction_IDs*

| Customer_ID | transaction_ID | Timestamp | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01/01/2022 17:00:00 | 1 | NULL |
| 1 | 1 | 01/01/2022 17:05:00 | NULL | Foo |
| 1 | 1 | 01/01/2022 17:10:00 | NULL | Bar |
| 1 | 1 | 01/01/2022 17:15:00 | 2 | NULL |
| 1 | 2 | 01/01/2022 17:20:00 | NULL | Wolf |

I want to create a view based on this data which follows the following format:

| Customer_ID | transaction_ID | Timestamp | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 01/01/2022 17:00:00 | 1 | NULL |
| 1 | 1 | 01/01/2022 17:05:00 | 1 | Foo |
| 1 | 1 | 01/01/2022 17:10:00 | 1 | Bar |
| 1 | 1 | 01/01/2022 17:15:00 | 2 | Bar |
| 1 | 2 | 01/01/2022 17:20:00 | NULL | Wolf |

Essentially I want to "roll" the data up so that the Value1 and Value2 are the most recent value for that transaction_id at a given timestamp.

I have tried things like PARTITION BY OVER statements but it this concatenates the values into a list instead of giving the most recent value(for strings) or their sum(for numeric values).

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT
transaction_id,
timestamp,
STRING_AGG(Value1) OVER(PARTITION BY transaction_id) AS Value1,
STRING_AGG(Value2) OVER(PARTITION BY transaction_id) AS Value2
FROM Database;
```

Comment: Where does the value1 of `4` come from?

Comment: I'm not clear on what you're asking for based on your sample data and description. You might want to look at the [mre] help page.

Comment: The 4 was a typo which has now been corrected

Answer (score 0):

To create a common value each row shares with the row the substitute should come from, you can first use the windowed version of `sum()` calculating a cumulative sum. Use `value1 IS NOT NULL` (or `value2 IS NOT NULL`), which as a Boolean expression in numerical context will be implicitly casted to `0` or `1` in MySQL. (In other flavors of SQL (and also in MySQL itself) this can be done explicitly by using a `CASE` expression.)

Then you can use this common value to partition by and use the `first_value()` window function to get the substitute value which will be in the, be the order of the timestamps, first row of the rows sharing a common value, i.e. in the partition.

Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT customer_id,
       transaction_id,
       timestamp,
       first_value(value1) OVER (PARTITION BY transaction_id,
                                              cv1
                                 ORDER BY timestamp ASC) AS value1,
       first_value(value2) OVER (PARTITION BY transaction_id,
                                              cv2
                                 ORDER BY timestamp ASC) AS value2
       FROM (SELECT customer_id,
                    transaction_id,
                    timestamp,
                    value1,
                    value2,
                    sum(value1 IS NOT NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY transaction_id
                                                  ORDER BY timestamp ASC) AS cv1,
                    sum(value2 IS NOT NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY transaction_id
                                                  ORDER BY timestamp ASC) AS cv2
                    FROM elbat) x;
```

(Untested because you failed to deliver the example as consumable DDL and DML as you should have.)

Answer (score 0):

An old method *(also works in MySql 7.x)*, is to use variables.

> ```
> select Customer_ID, transaction_ID, Timestamp, Value1, Value2
> from
> (
>   select Customer_ID
>   , Timestamp
>   , case 
>     when (value1 is not null or transaction_ID != @transId) 
>      and @val1 := value1
>     then value1
>     else @val1
>     end as Value1
>   , case 
>     when (value2 is not null or transaction_ID != @transId) 
>      and @val2 := value2
>     then value2
>     else @val2
>     end as Value2
>   , @transId := transaction_ID as transaction_ID
>   from your_table
>   cross join (select @transId:=0, @val1:=0, @val2:='') vals
>   order by Customer_ID, transaction_ID, Timestamp
> ) q
> ```

| Customer_ID | transaction_ID | Timestamp | Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 17:00:00 | 1 | *null* |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 17:05:00 | 1 | Foo |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 17:10:00 | 1 | Bar |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-01-01 17:15:00 | 2 | Bar |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-01-01 17:20:00 | *null* | Wolf |

*Side-note, the sort order in the sub-query matters in this method.*

Another method is to use correlated sub-queries

```
select Customer_ID, transaction_ID, Timestamp
, coalesce(Value1, (select t2.Value1 
   from your_table t2 
   where t2.transaction_ID = t.transaction_ID
   and t2.Value1 is not null
   and t2.Timestamp < t.Timestamp
   order by t2.Timestamp desc
   limit 1
  )) as Value1
, coalesce(Value2, (select t2.Value2
   from your_table t2 
   where t2.transaction_ID = t.transaction_ID
   and t2.Value2 is not null
   and t2.Timestamp < t.Timestamp
   order by t2.Timestamp desc
   limit 1
  )) as Value2
from your_table t
order by Customer_ID, transaction_ID, Timestamp;
```

Demo on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7ed6c6780cd71643297eadc8978774ac)*

Answer (score 0):

Traditional way (use subqueries as column expressions):

```
select
  t1.Customer_Id
  , t1.transaction_id
  , t1.Timestamp
  , (select t2.value1
        from testable t2 
        where t2.Customer_Id=t1.Customer_Id
        and t2.transaction_Id=T1.transaction_Id
        and t2.TimeStamp=(select max(TimeStamp) as V1_TS
                         from testable t3
                         where t3.Customer_Id=t2.Customer_Id
                         and t3.transaction_Id=t2.transaction_Id
                         and t3.Value1 is not null
                         )
       ) LastVal1
  , (select t2.value2
        from testable t2 
        where t2.Customer_Id=t1.Customer_Id
        and t2.transaction_Id=T1.transaction_Id
        and t2.TimeStamp=(select max(TimeStamp) as V1_TS
                         from testable t3
                         where t3.Customer_Id=t2.Customer_Id
                         and t3.transaction_Id=t2.transaction_Id
                         and t3.Value2 is not null
                         )
       ) LastVal2
  from testable t1
```